# Java GDAL: Permission denied when trying to open an file geodatabase (gdb)

Tags: gdal, file-geodatabase, java, maven

I'm trying to get the layers of a file geodatabase (.gdb), but I'm having problems with permissions. My Java code is like this:

```
import org.gdal.gdal.gdal;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    gdal.AllRegister();
    gdal.Open("C:\\Users\\myUser\\Downloads\\NLD_Multilayer_demo_sample" +
            "\\NLD_Multilayer_demo_sample.gdb");
}
```

When I execute the code, the output is:

```
ERROR 4: C:\Users\myUser\Downloads\NLD_Multilayer_demo_sample\NLD_Multilayer_demo_sample.gdb: Permission denied
```

I'm using Maven and the pom.xml has the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gdal</groupId>
    <artifactId>gdal</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I go to the terminal and do

```
$ ogrinfo -al "C:\Users\myUser\Downloads\NLD_Multilayer_demo_sample\NLD_Multilayer_demo_sample.gdb"
```

I do get the data. So what is wrong with the Java code?

I'm on Windows and I have the following env vars:

```
GDAL_DATA  C:\gdal\bin\gdal-data
PATH       C:\gdal\bin
PATH       C:\gdal\bin\gdal\apps
PATH       C:\gdal\bin\gdal\java
PATH       C:\gdal\bin\gdal\plugins
```

Comment: It's not valid to have a geodatabase in a folder with a `.gdb` suffix

Comment: @Vince I removed the .gdb from the outer folder so that it's now C:\Users\myUser\Downloads\NLD_Multilayer_demo_sample\NLD_Multilayer_demo_sample.gdb. Still doesn't work. And I think that wasn't an issue as the command on CLI works with the suffix.